# mulitple Optional parameters, Optional<List<Object>> vs List<Optional<Object>>, Java 8

Tags: list, java-8, option-type

I'm newbie, I want to understand a little more of *how must to use Optional*?

```
public class UsingOptional {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    multipleOptional(null, null);
  }

  public static void multipleOptional(Optional<String> string1, Optional<Integer> string2) {
    string1.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("string1:" + s));
    string2.ifPresent(s -> System.out.println("string2:" + s));
  }

}
```

Why I can't to do this **`multipleOptional(null, null);`** ?

What are the correct ways to call **`multipleOptional`** method?

What is the difference (considerations that I must take into account) between **`Optional<List<String>>`** and **`List<Optional<String>>`**?

Comment: *`multipleOptional(null, null); // Why I can't to do this?`*: you can do that (although that would be terrible, `null` values on top of `Optional`-typed method parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, it’s important to recognise that the whole point of having an Optional variable is to get away from having nulls, and so having to check for nulls.  After all, if you have to check an Optional variable for null each time it’s used, then it’s pretty pointless having/using Optional in the first place.

To put it another way, an Optional variable should never be null - ie, it should never be initialised to null, never be assigned the value of null, and any/all methods that return a value of Optional should never return null.   In all these cases, Optional.empty() should be used instead.

So, by honouring this contract, Optional forces you to always explicitly handle the case where data is not present, and not have to worry about NullPointerExceptions.

If you are getting used to Optionals, then I’d recommend not using Strings, but instead create your own classes (`Optional<Employee>`, etc) with ‘getters’ that would throw NPEs if called on null.  As per your example, it’s too easy with Strings to not call methods on them, and so not experience the pain that prompted the introduction of Optional.

> Why I can't to do this multipleOptional(null, null); ?

Of course the language allows you to do this, although it breaks the implicit contract I just said about Optional above.  The immediate result on breaking this contract is that you’d get a NullPointerException on the `ifPresent` call.

> What are the correct ways to call multipleOptional method?

By using “Optional”s !  The two most common sources of Optionals (other than your own code) are Streams and database accesses, where a single result is being returned (but where the library cannot assume that there actually will be a result).  For example, your code could be called as follows :

```
Optional<String> name1 = employees.stream().filter(e -> e.getOffice() == 1234).findFirst().map(Employee::getName);

Optional<String> name2 = nameRepository.findById(1234);

multipleOptional(name1, name2);
```

Notice how this code will work correctly even if there are no employees nor names found.

> What is the difference (considerations that I must take into account) between `Optional<List<String>>` and `List<Optional<String>>`?

Personally, I think both are pretty pointless.   As indicated above, Optionals are typically used when retrieving a single result which may or may not be present.  As such, they’re not typically used with Lists - after all, if a result is not present, then you just wouldn’t have it in the list (for example, if a query that is coded to return a list of objects happens to return zero rows, then you’d just get an empty List - no need to worry about Optionals).

As such, I don’t think I’ve ever seen an `Optional<List<>>` before - again, no results is handled fine by an empty List.

Likewise, the second should be where you have a List of Strings where each may or may not be present (or be null without Optionals).  Again,  if the value isn’t present, then it probably shouldn’t have been added to the List in the first place.